# how to use existing text editor for my RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

for the example at [voegella.de](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseEditors/article.html), I just want to use the built-in text editor to edit Person's name. I just want to learn how to use the text editor in this plugin: **org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor**

Comment: What are you asking?  Do you have a file in the workspace?  A POJO?  Do you want a text editor, or something more like the PDE editor where you'll be editing attributes?  Please write down 1) what you start with, 2) what you would like your user to see, and 3) what you want to end up with.

Comment: Sorry ! I am new to RCP, I want to learn how to use the text editor, it will be complex for me to write my own text editor or xml editor and, for many cases there are already plugins to accomplish my need

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to express my question well, I am an Chinese...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default text editor `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` in your own RCP apps by including the *org.eclipse.ui.editors* plugin (and all of its dependencies).  You can also subclass `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor` from the plugin that you mentioned.  Information on working with the platform text editors is available at http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_jface.htm

You should also check out http://www.eclipse.org/articles/ and information in the section http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_Official_Eclipse_FAQs#Implementing_Support_for_Your_Own_Language

Comment: By including `org.eclipse.ui.editors`, one of the dependencies is `org.eclipse.ui.ide`... I have read that it is not an RCP friendly plugin and should not be used as a dependency. How would one deal with that if I wanted to add the default text editor?

Comment: Yes, to use the proper TextEditor you are shipping the ui.ide.  Eclipse SDK itself is an RCP app, so I'm not sure what "not RCP friendly" means, although it brings in a lot of other plugins.  The alternative is to look at `org.eclipse.jface.text` for `TextViewer`.  That can be used to create your own text editor.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I have an RCP app of my own and I have read that it is not good to ship `org.eclipse.ui.ide` with your own RCP plugin (hence it not being RCP friendly). So that would mean that if I want a text editor in my RCP, I would have to create my own?

Comment: Yes, using TextViewer or SourceViewer (that's what the main TextEditor uses).